# How to detect if a Python Thread is being killed?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have my own `Thread` called `TimeBasedLogThread`. I would like to fire a function `my_function` when the `TimeBasedLogThread` is being killed because the main process is exiting. I would like to do it from within this object. Is it possible to do so?

Here is my current approach:

```py
class TimeBasedBufferingHandler(MemoryHandler):
    # This is a logging-based handler that buffers logs to send
    # them as emails
    # the target of this handler is a SMTPHandler

    def __init__(self, capacity=10, flushLevel=logging.ERROR, target=None,
                 flushOnClose=True, timeout=60):
        MemoryHandler.__init__(self, capacity=capacity, flushLevel=flushLevel, 
                                     target=target, flushOnClose=flushOnClose)
        self.timeout = timeout  # in seconds (as time.time())

    def flush(self):
         # Send the emails that are younger than timeout, all together
         # in the same email

class TimeBasedLogThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, handler, timeout=60):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.handler = handler
        self.timeout = timeout

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.handler.flush()
            time.sleep(self.timeout)

    def my_function(self):
        print("my_function is being called")
        self.handler.flush()


def setup_thread():
    smtp_handler = SMTPHandler()
    new_thread = TimeBasedLogThread(smtp_handler, timeout=10)
    new_thread.start()
```

In my main thread, I have:

```py
setup_thread()

logging.error("DEBUG_0")
time.sleep(5)
logging.error("DEBUG_1")
time.sleep(5)
logging.error("DEBUG_2")
```

The `time.sleep(5)` releases the main thread 5 seconds before the timeout of my other thread. So, I receive the first 2 emails with "DEBUG_0" and "DEBUG_1", but not the last one "DEBUG_2" because the main process exits before the timeout has finished.

I would like to link the class `TimeBasedLogThread` and the function `my_function` that will flush (send the emails) before exiting. How can I do that? I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/threading.py) of `threading` but I did not understand what method I could use.

Comment: You say, "fire a function." The only way a function can be "fired" is, some thread must call it. Which thread do you want that to be? The thread that is being killed? the thread that is doing the killing? Some other thread?

Comment: @SolomonSlow You're right! I want the function `my_function` to be called by `TimeBasedLogThread`, which is the thread being killed.

Answer (score 0):

Build your function as a Thread too. (Ex: AfterDeadThread)

You have two strategy here:

- TimeBasedLogThread call AfterDeadThread before die
- AfterDeadThread check if TimeBasedLogThread is alive or not, if not it will run some methods

Answer (score 0):

Extend `run()` method (representing the thread’s activity) to fire the `on_terminate` handler passed to custom thread’s constructor as keyword argument.

On a slightly changed custom thread class (for demonstration):

```
from threading import Thread
import time, random

class TimeBasedLogThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, handler, timeout=2, on_terminate=None):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.handler = handler
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.terminate_handler = on_terminate

    def run(self):
        while True:
            num = self.handler()
            if num > 5:
                break
            time.sleep(self.timeout)
            print(num)

        if self.terminate_handler:
            self.terminate_handler()


def my_term_function():
    print("my_function is being called")


f = lambda: random.randint(3, 10)

tlog_thread = TimeBasedLogThread(f, on_terminate=my_term_function)
tlog_thread.start()
tlog_thread.join()
```

Sample output:

```
3
4
5
4
5
my_function is being called
```

Comment: Thanks! But I forgot to tell that my `TimeBasedLogThread` is being killed because the main process is being killed.

Comment: @vinzee, are you catching the reason of main thread fail? how's the main processes being killed?

Comment: The main thread is being killed because there is no more instructions to run.

Comment: @vinzee, the main thread will wait until the running threads are completed. You may share more context to show your main thread

Comment: I added some details to help you understand what my problem is!

Comment: I don't get even "DEBUG_1"

Comment: and what's the behaviour when you reduce the timeout `TimeBasedLogThread(smtp_handler, timeout=3)` ?

Comment: I receive "DEBUG_0" and that's all

Comment: @vinzee, so you need another mechanism instead of playing with timers